# What is the translation of the song sung on the Rotarran?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon-language

In the DS9 episode "*Soldiers of the Empire*" the crew of the Klingon Bird-of-Prey *Rotarran* sing a song.

Unfortunately, I don't speak Klingon - what is the translation of that song?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Memory Alpha this is the "[Warriors Anthem](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Warrior%27s_Anthem)":

> Hear! Sons of Kahless.
> Hear! Daughters too.
> The blood of battle washes clean
>
> The Warrior brave and true.
>
> We fight, we love, and then we kill.
> Our lives burn short and bright,
> Then we die with honor and join our fathers in the Black Fleet where
> we battle forever, battling on through the Eternal fight.

Note that Martok gave a order during the song, which does not seem to be part of it.

Comment: What a coincidence that the English translation rhymes ;)

Comment: If you check the link, you'll note that the *literal* translation doesn't rhyme -- but a good *interpreter* will apply some creative license to ensure that the spirit of the thing comes through as well as the letter.